# How to get a list of all global declarations of a C/C++ program using Clang?

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm

I'm trying to write a program that lists all of the publicly exported variables and functions of a C or C++ program by using Clang.

I followed part 05 of [this tutorial](http://amnoid.de/tmp/clangtut/tut.html), but it doesn't work for current version of clang. Above that, I got [some hints](https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial) that `CompilerInstance` can make the code shorter, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it.

How would you implement this functionality? Can you give me any pointers into the right direction? For example: is there a large hash table of globally declared variables or do I have to traverse the AST?

Comment: For up-do-date code samples using Clang as a library, see https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way. The result is [AutoFFI](https://github.com/AutoFFI/AutoFFI), an FFI bindings generator built on top of Clang. I'll post the details on how it is done if I have the time.

Comment: seems this project no longer exists?

Answer (score 2):

*publicly exported* - do you mean symbols with external linkage?

You can use [`nm`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html) on object files, shared libraries and executables with `--extern-only --defined-only --demangle` options to display defined symbols with external linkage. Symbol type field tells you what kind of symbol it is, global variables normally have types B, b, C, D, d, G, g, R, r, S, s and W, w for static data members of templates declared in header files and function-scope statics.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the case. But I'd like to have the list of symbols straight from the source code so I can tamper with them.